# Why can I establish SSL Session to MYSQL from Mysql Client, but not DbEaver 8.0

Tags: mysql-8.0, tls-1.2

```ini
[mysqld]

ssl=ON

ssl_ca=ca.pem

ssl_cert=server-cert.pem

ssl_key=server-key.pem

require_secure_transport=ON

tls_version=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3
```

Results:

mysql client remote = Tls Session connects.

dbeaver remote SSL Enabled = Tls session fails, Failure. The driver has not received any packets from the server

```ini
[mysqld]

ssl=ON

ssl_ca=ca.pem

ssl_cert=server-cert.pem

ssl_key=server-key.pem

#require_secure_transport=ON

tls_version=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3
```

mysql client remote = Tls Session connects.

dbeaver remote = Connects but does not Establish Tls session.

dbeaver remote SSL Enabled = Tls session fails, Failure. The driver has not received any packets from the server